# Best Practices for Securing a Meteor/Node Server

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, security, meteor

What are the best practices for securing a Meteor.js app, assuming that we have already taken care of CSRF attacks, have proper user input validation, removed `auto-publish` and `insecure` packages?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have done most of the stuff already.

Additionally:

- Don't forget to use an SSL proxy in front of your Meteor app (that supports websockets).
- Make sure your database can only be accessed by your meteor app (firewall ip restriction).
- If you have any Meteor methods, make sure you check the user running them has permission to do so, especially when you are changing the database.
- If you are using non-meteor packages for authentication/user management make sure passwords are not stored in plain-text.
- Use `check` in all your Meteor methods, publish functions, & your allow & deny rules to ensure the data type and their structure is enforced so nothing else can cause damage. Using the `audit-argument-checks` package can help make you enforce strictness on this too.
- Make sure your Meteor server's time is correct.
- On your server side, make sure you don't declare variables inside of closures without the use of the `var` keyword (as the variables may jump between users).
- Make sure you always handle the case where documents are not found on the server (i.e don't do `collection.findOne(xx).yy` (as this can crash and reveal information, you should check the document exists first).
- Make sure `eval` isn't used anywhere (I think that one should be obvious enough) - Especially with meteor since stuff run in `eval` such as a globally scoped variable, even from a project, can be accessed anywhere (which is goes against how the warehouse engine system works).
- Never publish `services` (in the users collection) to any client, only a subportion of it without the `resume` set. (This is sometimes done with 3rd party logins to expose more user info to the client, but it can reveal a bit too much).

Not sure of any others, the main ones are removing the `insecure` and `autopublish` packages to make your own rules.

Sorry that doesn't look very nice, im not sure how to put a space underneath each item.

Comment: To add on to your 5th point, it's good practice to add the `audit-argument-checks` package to mandate using `check` on method and publish arguments.

Comment: Yup! I had no idea about that package. I've added it in